# What kind of tape should I use to tape the SSD in my system? And is it safe if cables touch heatsink/PCB board inside the system? Picture inside

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, cpu, sata, cooling

Apologize for stupid question.

I installed SSD into my firewall, the company that made it (Lanner FW-7551) sell separate HDD kit to mount HDD in it but it's a very old machine and I doubt they still sell it.

So, I have no choice but to tape the SSD and I got 2 questions

1. What kind of tape should I use to tape the SSD? I assume normal tape won't last long due to heat.
2. The unit has soldered CPU with heatsink and I need to run SATA and 4-pin cables. The space is very limited so the cable will touch the heatsink and the board itself, is this safe in long run because heatsink will run hot (I assume) and I'm afraid the cable will melt.

I can't find any high quality cable because these are very rare (4-pin Floppy to SATA) and mostly for old system. The only place I can find it is AliExpress for less than $2.

[image]

Comment: Unless you're going to pick it up frequently & run round the house with it, you can just lay it in place. It won't go anywhere. Re the heat sink, either check it with a thermometer or be brave & put a wet thumb on it. if it doesn't hurt, it won't hurt the wires either.

Comment: You can also use just one screw and place it where normal harddisks go. That's what we usually do. All you need to do is keep it from moving everywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't tape. Screw. Use at least two screws. I've even made cardboard holders for SSDs, it's not very hard.
2. Judging from the picture, you could route the cable in between the heat sinks. Touching a heat sink doesn't really hurt but there mustn't be any stress on the cable. If those you have don't fit properly get longer ones.